# Problems when i use "fscanf" in php

Tags: scanf

I have these sentences and words written in a text file named "titluri.txt". This "titluri.txt" have inside:

> "word1 word2 calculatorul nu porneste din cauza ca@ the computer does not start because#"

I use this php script:

..etc etc
$fisier1 = fopen("titluri.txt", "r");
while((!feof($fisier1)) && ($citeste = fscanf($fisier1, "%s\t%s\t%[^@]s\t%[^#]s\n"))){

list($baza_de_date,$tablou,$subiect,$subiect_en) = $citeste;} etc etc.

But I can't understand why $subiect_en have no effect. When read from text file "word1" appear, "word2" appear, sentence "calculatorul nu porneste din cauza ca" appear, but "the computer does not start because" is nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

try this `"%s\t%s\t%[^\t]%[^#\n]"`